# Count how many ordered values there are in a list

Tags: java, list, algorithm

Following the code below:

```
public static int countConsecutiveGroups(List<Integer> list) {
    int count = 0;
    int consecutiveCount = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1))) {
            consecutiveCount++;
        } else {
            consecutiveCount = 1;
        }

        if (consecutiveCount == 5) {
            count++;
            consecutiveCount = 0; // Reset the count for the next group
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I have the following problem, when giving it a list of numbers ordered ascending e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7...]` it returns that there are five consecutive values from lowest to highest. But if I give it a list that is also ordered but with repeated values, for example `[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5...]`, it does not return that there is an ordered sequence of numbers.

I want it to return how many ordered sequences of five numbers there are.

```
e.g. [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5] // This should return me 2 

// Because there are the following stairs.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// And the original list subtracting these two ordered lists should be:
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm really having trouble following your problem description. I especially have no idea where the whole `if (consecutiveCount == 5) {  consecutiveCount = 0; // Reset the count for the next group }` comes form. What groups? Why the number five? Why is none of this explained in your post?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I'm making a program that sees what poker plays there are in a randomly created deck. In this case it is counting how many stairs there are. The decks are created randomly and are stored in a multidimensional list `List<List<String>> hands = new ArrayList<>();` when created they leave something like this: `[[spades AS, diamonds 9, hearts K, clubs 9 , clubs K], [clubs Q, spades 9, clubs 9, clubs K, hearts 2], [spades 6, spades Q, clubs 4, hearts 10, spades 10]]`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Then I separate the values of the suits and count how many. For the straight, only the values are needed since there are five cards in ascending order. With a map it leaves me with this `{Q=2, AS=1, 2=1, 4=1, 6=1, 9=4, K=3, 10=2}` and passing it to values would look like this `[1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14]`.Before I added only one value of each card, that is, 1 ace, 1 q, 1 2...etc. But I realized that there can be more than one straight in a hand and I decided to add as many values as there are 1 ace, 2q.etc. But with the method in the post it doesn't w

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code :
If there is a sequence of 6 numbers or more, the count++ operation is launched too. In fact, the value of the variable consecutiveCount arrives to 5 when there is a sequence of 6 numbers or more.